# Having a function that returns int how can I run it in a separate thread using boost?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I know it looks not necessary but I hope that it would help me find memory leak.
So having a function inside a class that returns int, how can I call it from another function of that class (call it so that function that returns int would run in another thread)?

Comment: You want thread1 to call foo(), but foo()'s response to show up in thread2?

Comment: no I want thread1 to call foo so that foo would run in another thread and return int to thread1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operating system will not reclaim memory leaks in worker threads.  That's not how it works.

Fix your bugs.  The world doesn't need any more crappy software.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to find a memory leak in a function by having it called from another thread?  That is like trying to find a needle in a haystack by adding more hay to the stack.

Comment: And because of the potential non-determinism, having someone shuffle the hay in between searches for the needle.

Comment: I hope mem leak is in that function. and I hope OS will clean up after me when function will return results and thread will be deleted=)

Comment: @Kab Thread "deletion" (as you call it) will simply unwind the stack, which is what happens when a function returns anyway. A memory leak means that you are calling `new` or `malloc()` without a matching `delete` or `free()`.

Comment: @Kabumbus:  If that is your goal, you are doing it (debugging) wrong.  The goal of debugging is to remove a bug, not attempt to hide it so the OS cleans up after you (which won't even happen in this case ... threads share a heap - so the OS won't clean up until after your process exits).  Find your memory leak and correctly free the memory.  There are numerous strategies for doing so.

Answer (score 2):

Thread programming 101:

1. Spawn a new thread ("thread2") that invokes a new function ("foo").
2. Have the original thread join against thread2 immediately after the spawn.
3. Read a global variable that foo() has written its final value to.

Notice that foo() cannot return its value to the original thread; it must write the value to some shared memory (ie, global variable). Also note that this will not solve your memory leak problem, or even make it obvious where your memory leak is coming from.

Look for memory leaks with [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). And read a book or tutorial about multithreading.